# Collection Data in Lua

Tags: file, lua

I am relatively new to writing Lua, but this should be a relatively simple solution.

I am doing an analysis of the Data printed. I want to able to save the data printed on a file, perhaps a notepad, so that instead of printing the value store on a file. For example:

```
if VariableOne == nil and VariableTwo ~= nil and VariableThree == true then
    if VariableTime == nil then
        VariableTime = GetTime()
    end
    else if VariableTime ~= nil then
        print("Variable values have been met for "..GetTime() - VariableTime)
        VariableTime = nil
    end
end
```

I want it to collect the timer in a fashion such as a list so that I may use in an excel:

```
34.2
43.3
12.2
45.7
...
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: instead of printing, I want the value "GetTime() - VariableTime" to be added to a file such as notepad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the data to a file, open a file and write the data:

```
local f = assert(io.open('output.txt', 'w'))
f:write(tostring(GetTime() - VariableTime) .. '\n')
-- write more data
f:close()
```

For more information, read [PiL: The I/O Library](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.html).